# Why SSIS OData connector suddenly started to raise VS_ISBROKEN exception?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm maintaining SSIS jobs executions. Recently one of the packages that is using data flow where source is an OData connector started to raise the following exception:

> An Error occurred when detect the document payloadkind

What's interesting is the fact, that this package runs successfully when executed in debug mode in VS 2017
It fails when executed from SSISDB catalog or through SQL Agent Job.
Additionally, it runs successfully on MSSQL server first time after deployment and then starts fail during next executions (until re-deployed again)

I'm running this package through:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU5) (KB4475776) - 13.0.5264.1 (X64)   Jan 10 2019 18:51:38   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 1439s3: ) (Hypervisor)

I would really appreciate your advisory on solving this issue.